# time.sleep not working as expected when adding end= to print()

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to print out a message with a pause of 0.2 second between each character. I added an end="" to my print() method so that the message appears on 1 line, but when I start the thread only 1 character is printed before pausing until the remaining sleep time is over and the rest of the message is printed.

The program works fine without the end="", but I'm not sure why.

```
import time,threading

msg = "68 111 110 117 116 115 32 97 114 101 32 98 111 109 98 "
msg = [int(x) for x in msg.split()]

def print_msg():
    for c in msg:
        print(chr(c),end=""),time.sleep(0.2)

threading.Thread(target=print_msg).start()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Happy to see that an OP can provide an executable example! The problem is simple, stdout has a cache, you need to flush the result:

```
import time, threading

msg = "68 111 110 117 116 115 32 97 114 101 32 98 111 109 98 "
msg = [int(x) for x in msg.split()]

def print_msg():
    for c in msg:
        print(chr(c), end="", flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.2)

threading.Thread(target=print_msg).start()
```